# Infinite dividing by 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop, division

I'm just a beginner in python. Im trying to make a script which divides a number (user input) infinitly by 2. I mean if user inputs it should divide it like this:
"40/2
20/2
10/2
5/2
2.5/2
..."
My Code looks like this

```
print ('please insert a number')
num = input()
num=float(num)
while(num<1000):
    print(num/2)
```

Output is just user input divided by 2, and then the result is looped for ever.
What can I do next to make my code as I want?

Comment: What is your desired output? I'm guessing it's not an infinite loop.

Comment: @jpp let say that user input is 40.
the output should look like this:
40
20
10
5
2.5
1.75
and so on in infinity

Comment: So your program will *never* end?

Comment: @jpp yup, that's the point. I'm doing it just because I'm curious how infinite dividing by 2 would look like.

Comment: Note that doing ``num/2`` will only give you the result of that operation. It will *not* change the value of ``num``. To do so, you must explicitly overwrite ``num`` in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct an infinite loop via a condition which is always `True`, e.g. scalar `True`:

```
num = float(input('Please insert a number:\n'))

while True:
    num /= 2
    print(num)
```

In practice, this isn't useful. You can, for example, easily insert a `break` statement so that your loop stops when you reach a lower bound. Here we end the loop when the `float` value is indistinguishable from `0`.

```
num = float(input('Please insert a number:\n'))

while True:
    num /= 2
    print(num)
    if num == 0:
        break
```

Example with initial input of `500`:

```
Please insert a number:
500
250.0
125.0
62.5
...
3.06e-322
1.53e-322
8e-323
4e-323
2e-323
1e-323
5e-324
0.0
```

Comment: Works! At some point of the loop it outputs 0.0. Can I make it somehow to end the loop when output = 0.0?

Comment: @MiłoszMazurek, see update. If this solves your problem, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left).

Answer (score 1):

Looping the input forever doesn't make much sense, as you will just get stuck in an infinite loop and, even if it had a point, you would eventually end up with a float type `0.0`, as this operation goes to 0.

If you want to ask the user to divide the provided number by 2 n-times, here is a short program that can do it:

First, you need to ask the user to give you the number he wants to divide:

`number = int(input("Insert the number you want to divide by 2: "))`

Next, you gonna ask for the number of times you want to divide by 2:

`n = int(input("How many times you want to divide the number by 2?: "))`

Notice the `int` before the `input` - these will convert `str` type given by the `input` function `int` type. If this seems too much at once, you can just do it like this:

```
n = input("How many times you want to divide the number by 2?: ") 
n = int(n)
```

Now, you can write the logic. We can use the `**` operator to first, raise our `2` by `n` power and secondly, divide the number (remember the math operations order):

```
answer = number / 2 ** n
print(answer)
```

Example output for number `242` divided `9` times:

`0.47265625 #242 / 2 ** 9`

Comment: that's not what I'm trying to do but thanks. My target is to make infinite loop which divides input continously

Answer (score 0):

First, you should update num inside the while, and if you want the loop to stop when it reaches 0, you should use that as condition for the while statement

```
while num >= 0:
    num /= 2
    print(num)
```

Comment: the output is:
Insert the number you want to divide: 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/agama/Desktop/programowanko/python/dobre.py", line 2, in <module>
    while(true):
NameError: name 'true' is not defined